# Responsive Image for different mobiles and tablets

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to design a responsive page with bootstrap that is divided using height in **%** so that **scroll bar should not appear** for smaller device screens and it is to contain a section with a image that i want to be **responsive** for different sizes of mobiles and tablets but i am confused with the correct way to do that. i tried using bootstrap's img-responsive class but it overflows as per the code below when i run it on different devices in **intel XDK**. so i just need a proper direction to make this perfect.

**JSFIDDLE**: [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ankurlakhani/a00zzwjc/)

**Note: it is not overflowing in jsfiddle but not the same in intel XDK.i am using intel xdk as i want to use this page in a hybrid app.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>:: ૮૪ બેઠકજી ::</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="b/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/start.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="main_title">Title</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="photo">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="cont">
                <img src="img/aaa.jpg" id="start_img" class="img-responsive center-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="button">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <center><a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="start_a"> પ્રવેશ </a></center>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <center><div class="f1">heading </div></center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="a1">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <div class="f2">some text</div>
            </div>      
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                <div class="f2">some text</div> 
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>   

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="b/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    background:#ff9800;
    overflow:hidden;
}
header{height:14%;}
section#photo{height:50%;background:red;}
section#button{height:13%;}
footer{height:23%;background:green;}

div.main_title{
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.3em;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:0.5em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
}
a#start_a{margin-top:0.5em;font-size:1.6em;padding-left:1.5em;padding-right:1.5em;}

div.f1{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
div#a1{padding-top:0.5em;}
div.f2{
    color:brown;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    html,body{height:auto;overflow:auto;}
}
```

i have used the specified image size as 700px x 700px as i thought it would not blur on large devices.

Comment: Change `section#photo{height:50%;background:red;}` to `section#photo{background:red;}`

Comment: @Dino i am using height here so that the page fits into the container without a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of img tag use background image on #cont and set the size to cover:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="cont"></div>


#cont {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-image:url(../img/aaa.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: @alps.On Using the above solution, the image will no longer be responsive as we are specifying a fixed height 300px;so on large screens, it will be a very small image.

Comment: Use vh then, ought to work better for different sizes

Comment: i tried vh but its behaving the same. Can you direct me to some other successful method or an online tutorial for the same?